# How can I loop scraping data for multiple pages in a website using python3x

Tags: python-3.x, loops, web-scraping

I need to do a loop and get the json data from the pages. Page URLs are generated as follows:

```
https: //*.*bounds=506,168,507,169
https: //*.*bounds=506,169,507,170
https: //*.*bounds=506,170,507,171
https: //*.*bounds=506,170,507,171
https: //*.*bounds=505,171,506,172
https: //*.*bounds=506,173,507,174
```

It is depending on the coordinates.

For example,

```
https: //*.*bounds=506,170,507,171           

       for Latitude:  50.6015314505
           longitude: 17.0410603428

https://*.*bounds=508,163,509,164

       for Latitude:  50.859299
           longitude: 16.3206665
```

I think this loop will have to include something like this:

```
https: //*.*bounds= {lat}, {lon}, {lat + 1}, {lon + 1}?
```

**restrictions:**

- minLongitude = 140
- maxLongitude = 242
- minLatitude = 490
- maxLatitude = 549

How to do this in Python 3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
for lat in range(490, 550):
    for lon in range(140,243):
        print("%d,%d,%d,%d" % (lat, lon, lat + 1, lon + 1))
```